# Avoid downloading images using Beautifulsoup and urllib.request

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib, urlopen

I am using `BeautifulSoup` (`'lxml'` parser) with `urllib.request.urlopen()` to get text information from a website. However, when I check the network section in my Acitivity Monitor, I see that python downloads a lot of data. This suggests that not only the text is downloaded, but the images as well.

Is it possible to avoid downloading images when webscraping with BeautifulSoup?

Comment: ? Can you actually see raw image bytecode written in your response? Otherwise I'm not sure why you'd be downloading images. Images are usually stored separately in a `<img>` with `src` attribute - HTML scrapers will contain a link to the image represented as text, but not actually force downloading of the image because you never told it to follow the link.

Comment: I suspect the page simply has more data than you think it should. Inline JS can pack a punch.

Comment: i checked the 'soup' result and saved it to a text file. you are right, it was 256 kB and there were `<img>` attributes linking to the actual images. thanks for your help Akshat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's unlikely as images are not on the page they are in `<img src="/here/goes/this/img"..`. The browser or `urllib` has to make multiple trips to where-ever the static files like JS, img, CSS are. One possible solution to reduce size is request for zipped content.

Add `"Accept-Encoding":"gzip"` header to the `Request` object. If the server supports it, the size reduction will be good. You will then `gzip.decompress()` it to get string data.